# Selenium python program freezes at get() function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-iedriver

A simple python program freezes on the get() function of the selenium driver and does not return.

Please find below the written code:

```
        self.browser = webdriver.Ie("IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.browser.get(<url_in_quotes>)
        print('here') ##does not print
        self.browser.find_element_by_id('txtUname').send_keys(self.username)
        self.browser.find_element_by_id('txtPword').send_keys(self.password)
        self.browser.find_element_by_id('Submit').click()
```

I am using python 3.11 and IEDriver.

I have tried using implicit and explicit wait but the execution of the program freezes at the get() function. Please suggest a way out.

Comment: Without the actual link you trying to open this question is missing minimal debugging details

Comment: here `self.browser.get('url')` `url` is considered not as a variable name but as a string that contains word 'url', maybe it is gonna work if you get rid of quotes => you need not `get('url')`but just `get(url)`

Comment: I can not share the link. I am using the appropriate URL as an argument.

Comment: @Prophet How to extract minimal debugging details?

Comment: At least to provide the link to the page you are working on

Comment: @Prophet Sorry, I can not share the link. I got the following error after 300 seconds of program execution: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page to load.

Comment: You'll need to set the security zones to the same level in the browser.  See here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/

Comment: @pcalkins Thank you for the information. The script worked fine when I disabled the protected mode in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Pcalkins, I made the necessary configuration changes in IE settings and the python code worked.
Please refer to the link below for recommended settings:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/